# Do loop while with boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Can someone explain why I can't break the loop? To break the loop Player1Pass or Player2Pass should be false. Also is there a way to break a loop in the middle, for example, Player1Pass = true; BUT let the program finish the whole loop before ending the loop? - By the way I know that the code is not perfect. I have just started my experiences with Java. :)

```
        boolean Player1Pass = true;
        boolean Player2Pass = true;
        do{ 
        String answer;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println(pName1 +" would you like to DRAFT another card or PASS?" );

            answer = scan.nextLine();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("DRAFT")) {
                clsCard cardFace = new clsCard();
                System.out.println("Your new card is: " + cardFace);
            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {
                Player1Pass = true;
            }

        System.out.println(pName2 +" would you like to DRAFT another card or PASS?" );

            answer = scan.nextLine();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("DRAFT")) {
                clsCard cardFace = new clsCard();
                System.out.println("Your new card is: " + cardFace);
            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {
                Player2Pass = false;
            }


        }while(Player1Pass || Player2Pass);
}
}
```

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question.  Your question has two questions, and I am therefore struggling to work out what you're asking.

Comment: It current says "loop while Player1Pass is true, Player2Pass is true or both are true", that seems to be different to your description...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will need to change the `||` to `&&`:

```
}while(Player1Pass && Player2Pass);
```

If either returns `false`, then the whole statement will be `false` and it will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Player1Pass never changes the true value so the while will be executed everytime because the condition is an OR (if only one member is true all the condition is true).

I think you need to review your logic. Maybe should be `while (Player1Pass && Player2Pass)` and you have to change the original true state of one or both of them inside your code.